# Generalized Inverse of Distribution function

Tags: probability-theory

Given a distribution function $F$ one can define its generalized inverse as

$$F^{-1}(u)=\inf \{x\in \mathbb{R}| F(x)\ge u \}$$

I have just recently seen a definition $$F^{-1}(u)=\sup\{x\in \mathbb{R}| F(x)<u \}$$

and want to prove that these are equal. I have tried using the $\varepsilon$-property of the infimum but I could not conclude. This should be easy, but somehow I am stuck.

Comment: Can you use the fact that $\sup(A)=-\inf(-A)$?